# Ошибка конвертации CS1503

Tags: c#, linq

Ошибка  CS1503  Аргумент 2: не удается преобразовать из "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable" в "System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer".    Algorithm2

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str_1, str_2, str_3;
        using (var sr = new StreamReader("d:\\Lenovo\\nextLevel.txt"))
        {
            sr.ReadLine();
            str_1 = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.ReadLine();
            str_2 = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.ReadLine();
            str_3 = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        var result = str_1.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Union(str_2.Split(',').Select(int.Parse)).Distinct(str_3.Split(',').Select(int.Parse));
    }
```

[image: Ошибка]

это операции с множествами каждый str_ это строка в файле с набором чисел, там где при чтени отсутсвует присваивание - читается строка которая отвечает за кол-во чисел в следующей строке(в тех наборах). Нужно вывести числа, которые хоть раз входят в str_1 и 2, но не входят в str_3

[image: Пример]

Comment: А что сделать-то хотите? У вас есть два IEnumerable<int> вы их объедини, что дальше? Что вы хотели сделать за Union где пошёл Distinct?

Comment: решить и понять. Понять почему она возникла и как в будущем таких ошибок не допускать.

Comment: Что Вы хотите сделать кодом, а не публикацией своего вопроса) Ибо я, как и компилятор, Вашего замысла не поняли)

Comment: это операции с множествами каждый str_ это строка в файле с набором чисел, там где при чтени отсутсвует присваивание - читается строка которая отвечает за кол-во чисел в следующей строке(в тех наборах). Нужно вывести числа, которые хоть раз входят в str_1 и 2, но не входят в str_3

Comment: но тут выскочила ошибочка - впервые сталкиваюсь, гуглил не помогло

Comment: Откуда такой странный пример?   На входе 1,2,6,4 потом 2,3,4 - и входят в оба набора цифры 4 и 6. Третий набор 1, 4, 5 - и от 4 и 6 остаётся только 6.

Comment: в примере нету ком, я забыл, но они у меня в файле. На счёт выходных чисел - сам не понимаю условие одно пример другой.

Comment: это пример препода)

Comment: окей, то есть вам нужно не по текстовому описанию "вывести числа, которые хоть раз входят в str_1 и 2, но не входят в str_3" решить, а по конкретным числам подобрать верное описание, а потом уже записать его на Linq? А, я понял логику. Щас допишу ответ.

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы в файле была такая структура как в колонке входных данных, набор чисел может быть разный, просто я делал по этому примеру, ну и собственно решить задачу, я пытался решить на Linq, а раз взялся за это, то должен уже довести до конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нужно вывести числа, которые хоть раз входят в str_1 и 2, но не входят в str_3

"Хоть раз входят" - это на языке linq будет `Intersect`, а "не входят" - это `Except`. Смотрите:

```
string str_1 = "123,23,33,55";
string str_2 = "44,66,33,123";
string str_3 = "51,12,123";

var e1 = str_1.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
var e2 = str_2.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
var e3 = str_3.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

e1.Intersect(e2).Dump();

var result = e1.Intersect(e2).Except(e3);

result.Dump();
```

На этих конкретных числах: 123 и 33 входят в e1 и e2, но 123 есть в третьем. а 33 нету, итого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можете обратно записать в однострочник, я разбил для наглядности.

---

Для обновлённого вопроса (добавленного примера данных) логика такая:

```
string str_1 = "1,2,6,4";
string str_2 = "2,3,4";
string str_3 = "1,4,5";

var e1 = str_1.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
var e2 = str_2.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);
var e3 = str_3.Split(',').Select(int.Parse);

e1.Union(e2).Dump();

var result = e1.Union(e2).Except(e3);

result.Dump();
```

Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Словами это "найти элементы которые входят хотя бы раз в e1, е2 - но не входят в е3". А я первое условие подумал "входят одновременно и в е1 и в е2". В общем, спать пора, а не код писать.

Comment: видать задача мне была не правильно поставлена ибо вы сделали правильно по тому как написано в задаче, но выходные данные говорят о решении, которое я пытался осуществить

Comment: а что вы скажите о моей ошибке как её можно решить?

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы хотели круглый разьём воткнуть в квадратный. У Distinct внутри скобок ожидается компарер, а вы туда Ienumerable подали, это настолько разные вещи, что это не решается никаким приведением типов. Вам просто нужно решать больше задач на linq, осваивать функции - и постепенно придёт понимание.

Comment: спасибо, понял - больше практики

Comment: ух ты, не подскажите как вы просматриваете значения, которые находятся в e1 и result - это связано как-то с компилятором, ибо я при дебаге не видел значений, которые находились в result

Comment: Это такая маленькая программа типа блокнотика для по быстрого прототипирования кода на c#, называется linqpad - и в ней очень удобно писать запросы на linq. Весьма рекомендую.

Comment: я погуглил на счёт Dump(), то я так понял. что в VS его нет, или нужно что-то подключить?

Comment: Это не visual studio, это linqpad.

Comment: а так это что-то типо вывода, так?

Comment: А вы попробуйте. )) У нас на работе linqpad входит в обязательные инструменты разработчика, не только студия и решарпер. И на stackoverflow многие уже кто задавали вопросы по linq успели подсесть на эту штуку. )) Конечно это просто вывод. Но это очень клёвый редактор кода.

Comment: сделал, понял и угадал с догадкой. Спасибо!